# Why does the fit get worse when I remove a non-significant predictor from my path model?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, path-model

I am testing two path analysis models. Both models have the same predictors. The outcome variable is all that differs

- Model 1: Outcome variable is intention to use a face-to-face support service
- Model 2: Outcome variable is Intention to use a telephone support service

When I tested the models, the fit indices for both indicated a very good fit to the data. On the second model, however, for one of the variables, no significant paths are evident (to the outcome variable or any other IV). 
I would have expected the relationships to be significant based on correlations.

When I remove this predictor variable from the model, the fit is no longer acceptable.

**Why does the fit get worse when I remove a non-significant predictor from my path model?**

Comment: How does your model differ from a multiple regression? I think that's important information. If you just had a set of predictors all correlated and with a set of regression lines to the outcome variable, then you would have a saturated model with no fit statistics.

Comment: Do you remove the predictor variable, or do you fix the loading of the path to zero?